# Instantiating a class on Stack memory

Tags: c++

I have the following class which I wish to instantiate on stack memory:

```
class ClassOnStack {
   int arr[];

public:
    
   ...
   // somemethods();
}
```

I have three requirements, two of which are:

1. I wish to specify the size of arr while instantiating it through a constructor.
2. I want to instantiate this class entirely on stack. That is the array 'arr' should also be stored on stack.

The way I came up with is using templates and making new operator private.

```cpp
template<int ARRAY_LEN>

class ClassOnStack {

private:
  void *operator new(size_t size); //overloaded and private                                                                                                                                               

public:
  int array[ARRAY_LEN];

  ClassOnStack() {
  }

  ....
  // somemethods()
};
```

However this will require me to define the methods within the header file which I don't wish to do.
The third requirement is:

3. I wish to keep the implementation in the cpp file.

What are other approaches I can take ?

Comment: None that I can think of. As is often the case with weird requirements you seem to be trying hard to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: Your template solution also fails to satisfy the first requirement *I wish to specify the size of while instantiating it through a constructor*

Comment: I suppose you could call `alloca` from your constructor. That (non-standard) function allocates extra memory on the stack.

Comment: This is probably impossible because C++ has no notion of stack memory. The existence of a stack is an implementation detail. The closest analog C++ has is automatic storage, but that only maps to stack allocations in some contexts. Maybe if you clarify what you are trying to accomplish with this, we can just some alternatives that fit your needs.

Comment: Is this an academic exercise to implement `std::array` but way weirder?

Comment: Also, note that your `operator new` overload is effectively moot, since a) the standard new is still trivially usable and b) thing like `std::unique_ptr<ClassOnStack>` or `std::vector<ClassOnStack>` are still possible

Comment: @tadman No, trying to implement some multiprecision number type.

Comment: The size of something needs to be predictable, it can't vary wildly. Using a template argument to make it weird sizes is also in effect making a bunch of weird types. Why is the "stack" so important here?

Comment: **Just use `std::array` and move on with life**. Additionally, if there's no measurable performance difference, use `std::vector`. Remember, on some systems, notably Windows, stack space is quite limited, so you must be careful about how hard you lean on it.

Comment: @echelon Ok, I think there's a terminology barrier then. You don't actually care abort enforcing where the objects are located, you just don't want to manage dynamic memory for them, right?

Comment: Ok, lets say you implement this somehow, but what happens if the user does `a += b`, and after that `a` needs more bits than it has allocated?

Comment: @Brian61354270 thanks for pointing the problem with 'new' operator here.

Comment: PSA: ["Bignum" libraries exist](https://gmplib.org).

Comment: @Brian61354270 I do care about the performance. That's the main reason I wish the array to be on stack.

Comment: In our C++ code base, I implemented a `FastTemporaryBuffer<T, size=1024>` template class. It is purposed as a buffer to construct some data by following the construction with some `append`. As long as we are not appending more than `size` bytes, data is completely on stack and the process is blazing fast. If we append more, the class automatically calls `new` and will grow dynamically its allocated array, so no risk of buffer overflow like with a regular C array on stack. I don't know if this what you are trying to do, but this class proved very useful at least.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Don't plan to have that operation for this number type. Sorry, I know it sounds messed up to even call it a number type without that operation :D

Comment: @prapin : yes, that's the aim down the line. With the template implementation must have been in the header file, is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, it has to be in a header. I don't think there is any problem with that.

Comment: Your users will hate you (including yourself). `alloca` is the solution, but I believe you'll need to call it outside of the class, in the function that creates the variable (then placement-new into the resulting memory). But if I were you, I'd just use `vector` or `array`.

Comment: *I do care about the performance.* You're trying to create a solution for problem that doesn't exist. Getting values from heap has very little overhead (unless you access very fragmented memory routinely, say, `std::vector<std::vector<T>>`, but that won't be a problem in your class - maybe in the usage of it). In fact, using array may be far worse than e.g. using `std::vector` internally, because you disable move semantics this way. Don't optimise based on a hunch - write correct code and if and only if it doesn't meet requirements, then profile and solve the problem based on profiling.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, that alloca needs to be done where the object is intantiated. I did come across a way to do it that way. But it makes some assumption on how variables are stored. If I have more variables in this class, I can declare the arr variable as the last variable and then alloca the size I need. I will need a slight calculation to compute that size. The calculation is not hard but don't like that I have to make an assumption on the order in which variables are stored in memory.

Comment: What assumption do you mean?

Comment: If I need to control the arr size while instantiating, I will need to specify the size while doing alloca. Somethine like this : ```new (alloca(size))ClassOnStack()```. The size value will include the class size (excluding array size) + arraysize. Then I can just use arr[i] to access that member of the array. arr will be the last declared member, and the assumption is that the variables of class are stored in order of their declaration which iirc C++ guarantees.

Comment: Minor note, but you probably want `std::size_t` rather than `int`, but allocating a raw array that way probably blows your stack before the size difference becomes significant.

Comment: @Chris thanks. yes, shall change it anyways.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I think you have convinced me to use std::array for now.

Comment: Stack or heap, why do you care?

Answer (score 1):

To satisfy your number 2 and 3 requirements:

To keep the core implementation in the .cpp file and still be a template class on the stack, you could probably use the details pattern.

Declare your class that has the core implementation like this:

```
class ClassOnStackDetails {
private:
    int* _arr;
    size_t _arraySize;
public:
    ClassOnStackDetails(int* arr, size_t arraySize);
    void doSomething();
    int doSomethingElse();
};
```

Then your template class, the one that actually gets instantiated on the stack, can be declared in the same header file or in another that `#includes` the previous declaration.  The template class constructor just passes the array and its compile time size to the details class as a pointer. The public methods of the template class just forward to the details class where the implementation is not in the header file.

```
template <size_t ARRAY_LEN>
class ClassOnStack {

public:
    std::array<int, ARRAY_LEN> arr;

    ClassOnStack() : arr(), _details(arr.data(), arr.size()) {
        
    }

    void doSomething() {
        _details.doSomething();
    }

    int doSomethingElse() {
        return _details.doSomethingElse();
    }

private:
    ClassOnStackDetails _details;

};
```

Take note that I explicitly declared `_details` after `arr`. If your real work  gets more complicated, you can add an explicit `init` function to the details class that gets called by the template class constuctor.

Then your .cpp file has the implementation for ClassOnStackDetails:

```
#include "ClassOnStack.h"

ClassOnStackDetails::ClassOnStackDetails(int* arr, size_t arraySize) :
_arr(arr),
_arraySize(arraySize) {
   // additional intitialization
}


ClassOnStackDetails::doSomething() {
   // your code goes here
}

int ClassOnStackDetails::doSomethingElse() {
   // your code goes here
}
```

Then in code, you can simply say:

```
int foo() {
    ClassOnStack<52> deckOfCards;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works without any use of heap memory, with alloca(3):

```
#include <alloca.h>
#include <stddef.h>
class ClassOnStack {
 public:
  ClassOnStack(size_t size, int *buf): size_(size), buf_(buf) {}
  // ...
 private:
  // ...
  size_t size_;
  int *buf_;
};
#define ALLOCA_SIZE_AND_BUF(size) (size), alloca(size)
```

Use it like this:

```
ClassOnStack cs(ALLOCA_SIZE_AND_BUF(size));
```

Unfortunately it's too easy to use it incorrectly, e.g. if the user accidentally calls the constructor directly, and the forgets to destroy the data `buf_` points to. It's possible to make that harder, but it's not possible to get rid of the macro.